# how to add timer countdown action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timer

I want to add a temporary counter descending so if they end the count goes to another page has experimented with JavaScript, but that does not work

```
<script>
    setTimeout("doSomething()", 500);

    function doSomething() {
        @Url.Action("ControlPanelAdmin", "Account")
        setTimeout("doSomething()", 500);
    }
</script>
```

What is the correct way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

in JS redirect is `window.location.href='url'`

```
function countdown()
{
      window.location.href="@Url.Action("ControlPanelAdmin", "Account")";
}

setTimeout(function(){countdown();}, 3000);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b6o5ypsb/)

Comment: Thank you for your interaction but the timing does not work once you open the page to never transmitted directly to the link "@Url.Action("ControlPanelAdmin", "Account")" What problem do you think?